# Achieve a multiple functionalities in a single PHP page

Tags: php, url, redirect

I want to achieve a particular functionality (eg: forgot password) in a single php page instead of redirecting to another page in each and every stage of changing the password.
For example, when user clicks on forgot password link.

1. Goto forgot.php
2. Send the link to email/mobile.
3. Verify the code.
4. Prompt user to enter new password.
5. Update the password.

I want to achieve all of the above functionalities in a single php page. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, look into AJAX and JavaScript. It's pretty simple once you get going!

Comment: Thanks.But how to receive the data after the step2?I should be using another php page to achieve this correct?Or its like,I have to enable the verify button(form) after step2?

Comment: Your requirement to shove all this functionality into a single php page is confusing. PHP can be split out into 10,000 file or a single one and you (as the user) would never know the difference. There's nothing architecturally or design-wise that changes. You could fit all of Facebook's PHP code into a single file but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I didn't mean that i wanted to achieve all the requirement in a single page.What I meant was a single unique functionality doesn't require multiple pages of redirection and data passing.I think you misunderstood my query..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its possible.

Through PHP itself, you can do it.

Depending upon url parameters/form posted values, you can switch the functionality.

e.g.

```
<?php
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : '';
switch ($page) {
  case 'forgot_form':
  // Your HTML and PHP here
  break;
  case 'prompt_change_password':
  // Your HTML and PHP here
  break;
//... AND MORE
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use AJAX to accomplish this.  You would need to do something along these lines:

1. User visits forgot.php which displays a form prompting for email/account name to recover.  This form shouldn't have a submit () button but rather a button that triggers JavaScript.
2. When the user clicks the button, the JS code collects the value in the field (email/username) and launches an AJAX request to the server providing this information. It can also change the input area to a "please wait" notification
3. Server receives the username/email and sends out an email if the account exists then returns a JSON response indicating if the account was found or not
4. The client-side JS code handles the AJAX complete event and either displays an "Account not found" message or informs the user to check their email and changes the visible element to the verification code input.
5. User enters the code and presses another button that triggers a JS call.
6. The JS function sends an AJAX request with the verification code.
7. The server verifies the code and sends a yes/no JSON response
8. The JS code handles the AJAX complete event and informs the client if the code is invalid or changes the visible element to the new password input
9. User enters the new password and presses a button that launches a JS call
10. The JS code sends the new password to the server via AJAX
11. The server sets the new password and answers with a success/failure message
12. The JS code handles the completion of the AJAX call and informs the client of success/failure, sending them to the login page on success.

Comment: Thankyou.But when I hide the forms,the blank space is present where I have the hidden forms.How to get rid of this?

Comment: Use display: none; instead of visibility: hidden;